# ReactJS ES6 Issue with import class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In ReactJS, I'm trying to do something very simple. I have a class that I created:

```
//SomeName.js
class SomeName {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In my React.component I have:

```
//Index.js
import React from 'react'
import SomeName from './parts/SomeName'

class Index extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        let newName = new SomeName("John Doe");
        this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
    }

    getName(){
        return newName;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pages-container">

                Hello {this.getName}

            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

However, I stick a debugger in my Index.js constructor, I get no reference to SomeName.  Every reference I've looked at shows it being done this way (not in ReactJS though), and I have no issues importing my components that I make, it's only when I'm trying to return this value.  I feel like there is something really simple that I'm missing, i just don't know what.  Can someone lend a hand?

Comment: Did you export SomeName?

Comment: If not try putting `export default` in front of `class SomeName`

Comment: @AR7 I actually just did that and was coming back to post the answer. That was my problem. Ugh!

Comment: Haha no worries. Good job figuring it out yourself.

Comment: @doubleya feel free to answer your own question, it might help somebody out in the future

Comment: So one thing I noticed @AR7 is that even though I'm able to see the console log under the import statement, SomeName is still undefined when I try to console.log(SomeName) in the constructor. Looks like i'm 50% there

Comment: So what i had was right, it looks like my problem was using the `debugger` doesn't seem to play nice but when you `console.log` you're able to see the proper variables.  Ugh, i don't know why it took me 2 days to figure that out.  Thanks a ton for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

1) You define `newName` as a local variable. To make it accessible in the `getName` you should assign it into `this`:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.newName = new SomeName("John Doe"); // fixed here
    this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
}

getName(){
    return this.newName; // and here
}
```

2) You should call the `getName` in the `render` method. Otherwise you will get the function, not the result:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="pages-container">

            Hello {this.getName()} //do not forget parentheses

        </div>
    )
}
```